# Set up own database in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, connection

I'm trying to make a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer, but instead of connecting to a existing database I want to make a new database where I can upload my own tables into. I know this is possible, because someone has done it on my other pc.

Trying to do 'new connection' always says that the network adapter could not make the connection. That is logical, because I want my own that I can use only on my pc.

Anyone knows how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Grtz!

Comment: You most probably don't want a new "*database*", you want a new *schema* which is done through `create user`.

Comment: You can't create a new database by setting up a new connection. You can install the Oracle database software on your own PC, or in a virtual machine running on your PC, and *then* create a new connection to that. SQL Developer is a client, not the database itself.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with SQL Developer.

Do you have a running database on your PC already?  Is it Express Edition (XE)?   Express Edition can only have one database.  If it is not XE, use DBCA ( Database Configuration Assistant ) to create the database.

If you do not have Oracle on your PC, then you need to download and install the binaries.  XE install creates the database during install.  Other versions of Oracle will prompt you if you want a database or use DBCA after the binaries are installed.

Are you sure you want a database and not just a new user/schema to store your tables?  See docs for "CREATE USER ..."  command to create a new user in an existing database.

Answer (score 3):

The CREATE DATABASE [databasename] command will create a new database. Make sure you're connected to the server that you want to create the database on.

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
```

You may need to supply more options depending on the configuration of the server. Also,

"To create a database, you must have the SYSDBA system privilege."

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5004.htm

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP does **not** want to create a new database.

Comment: It's possible that the OP doesn't really want to create a new database, but with the question stating " I want to make a new database", I answered it.

Comment: When I run your suggested `CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;` commend, getting errors are like: `Error starting at line : 1 in command -
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase
Error report -
ORA-01501: CREATE DATABASE failed
ORA-01100: database already mounted
01501. 00000 -  "CREATE DATABASE failed"
*Cause:    An error occurred during create database
*Action:   See accompanying errors.`